# Calculate Work in Progress from Timestamps

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table consisting of 250,000 rows. A small sample is shown below:

```
library('data.table')
stack <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
                              5, 6), 
                        Special = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                                                                 FALSE, FALSE), 
                        ENTER = structure(c(1453797143, 1453850662, 1453444763, 1453656563, 1453410022, 1453367723), 
                                          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
                        LEAVE = structure(c(1453803923, 1453856002, 1453450403,1453657823, 1453418123, 1453377382), 
                                          class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), 
                   .Names = c("ID", "Special", "ENTER", "LEAVE"), 
                   class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
                   row.names = c(NA, -6L))

stack
   ID Special               ENTER               LEAVE
1:  1   FALSE 2016-01-26 09:32:23 2016-01-26 11:25:23
2:  2   FALSE 2016-01-27 00:24:22 2016-01-27 01:53:22
3:  3    TRUE 2016-01-22 07:39:23 2016-01-22 09:13:23
4:  4   FALSE 2016-01-24 18:29:23 2016-01-24 18:50:23
5:  5   FALSE 2016-01-21 22:00:22 2016-01-22 00:15:23
6:  6   FALSE 2016-01-21 10:15:23 2016-01-21 12:56:22
```

I'm looking for the WIP (work in progress) at hourly intervals. This is a count of the number of instances that have entered, but not yet left at a specific time. I do this now with the following function:

```
get_WIPlevels <- function(data) {
  # determine range
  min <- round(min(data$ENTER), "hours")
  max <- round(max(data$LEAVE), "hours")
  range <- seq(from=min, to=max, by='hours')

  # create target data.table
  WIPLevels <- data.table(Timestamp = range, WIP = integer(length(range)))

  # calculate WIP values
  WIPLevels$WIP <- sapply(WIPLevels$Timestamp, function(x) 
    nrow(data[data$ENTER<=x & data$LEAVE > x,]))
  return(WIPLevels)
}
```

This works as expected and results in something like this:

```
get_WIPLevels(stack)
               Timestamp WIP
  1: 2016-01-21 10:00:00   0
  2: 2016-01-21 11:00:00   1
  3: 2016-01-21 12:00:00   1
  4: 2016-01-21 13:00:00   0
  5: 2016-01-21 14:00:00   0
 ---                        
137: 2016-01-27 02:00:00   0
```

However, it is not the fastest function. Applying it on the full dataset takes almost a minute:

```
system.time(get_WIPlevels(fulldata))
   user  system elapsed 
  53.72    2.15   56.19
```

Any suggestions to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with a rolling join

```
tr <- data.table(
  Timestamp = seq(lubridate::floor_date(min(stack$ENTER), "hour"), 
                  lubridate::ceiling_date(max(stack$LEAVE), "hour"), by = "hours"))
setkey(tr, Timestamp)

stack[, Timestamp := ENTER]
setkey(stack, Timestamp)

ms <- stack[tr, roll = +Inf]
ms[, .(WIP = sum(!is.na(ENTER) & LEAVE >= Timestamp)), by = Timestamp]
```

Comment: It doesn't give the correct result when there are multiple instances present at the same time. I'm not quite sure what goes wrong, because it works well in the example. I'm going to look into the rolling join and then come back to you.

Comment: Please, provide an example and I'll look into this if time permits - Thank you.